# Batch changing of Raster Bands of Multiple Rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, multi-band, image-segmentation, band

I have many rasters in my ArcGIS project, each with 4 bands.
At the moment, I am changing the raster bands, one by one, for each file:

- Red becomes Band 2
- Green becomes Band 1

And I am setting the Stretch Type to Minimum-Maximum, like on this screenshot:

[image: Target state of each Raster]

Problem is, it's about 300 Rasters and the manual job is just taking too long. I have checked the ArcGIS Toolbox and the help, but I have not found a way to do that as a batch job.

Marking all the rasters and change the properties for all of them all together does not work either.

Afterwards I want to set these settings from the Image Analysis for RGB Stretch for each of the rasters as well, but preferably not manually.

[image: Image Analysis RGB Stretch]

Unfortunately, I am just fresh at remote sensing and image analysis.

I am doing this because I need to visualize and enhance trees from satellite images. I got the images from this source: [link](https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/dop/dop/).

With the above mentioned settings I could change the picture in the following way, which is exactly what I am aiming for:

[image: From this]

To this:

[image: To this]

After some more research, I have discovered the ArcGIS tool "Apply symbology from layer", but it changes me only the bands and the min-max stretch and not the settings in the "image analyzis" window and it takes forever. It's been running now since 7 hours and I am scared that it crashes.

The final and most ideal outcome is that I can convert the red (tree) areas into a shapefile. Unfortunately, I have not come across a solution for that yet either.

Do you have a better way of doing all this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature extraction problem--as such, I would approach this problem differently. By altering the band combinations and adjusting the image histogram, you are essentially changing only how the image renders on your screen--however, the pixel values remain unchanged. Instead, I would recommend deriving useful indices from various band combinations. You can then use these indices to help extract your features of interest.

You wrote in the comments:

> I need to isolate only the trees. I am aiming for the parts where the
>   trees cover the streets. If I manage to convert the trees to a
>   shapefile, I want to make a clip with a street-shapefile and then only
>   have the chunks of the streets that are covered by trees. Everything
>   else will be irrelevant then. In case the conversion to shapefile
>   doesn't work, I can do that manually.

In your case, since you need to isolate vegetation over roadways, you can assume any healthy green vegetation over a roadway will be tree canopy cover. A simple approach would be to calculate the [Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index) from the red and near infrared bands of your imagery. The derived NDVI raster product will have a theoretical range of -1 to 1, where values closer to 1 indicate healthy green vegetation. From there, you can simply threshold the image by applying a rule such that any value >X is assigned a value of 1 and everything else a value of 0. Then convert the binary raster to a polygon shapefile and perform your overlay analysis with the roadway shapefile.

In sum:

1. Calculate NDVI using the [Raster Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm)
2. Threshold the NDVI raster using the [Raster Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/raster-calculator.htm).
3. Convert the binary raster of vegetation to polygon using [Raster to
   Polygon](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm)
4. Perform an [overlay analysis](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/an-overview-of-the-overlay-toolset.htm)

Also check out an [earlier answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152932/8104) that I provided which uses image segmentation and thresholding to extract features from 4 band NIR imagery. You can use this approach to extract vegetation from imagery.